# Update existing row instead of creating a new one in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

The code below is updating the MySQL table correctly, so when someone puts a number in team and a time in `cp2_arrival` it goes into the table. But when I do the same for the next time entry, it creates a new row and not update the existing row for that team.

This is my code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to Database, Contact Control: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$Team = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Team']);
$cp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cp']);


$sql="INSERT INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival)
VALUES (
 '".$Team."',
 '".$cp."00' 
)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do an UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: ive changed it to Update and im now getting Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival) VALUES ( '6', '115900' )' at line 1

Comment: Well, for me you need to do a select, if element present update that row, otherwise create a new one

Comment: and op the update is UPDATE table SET field = value, field = value WHERE etc etc etc

Comment: When you do update you need to pass the id as well ex: where id=9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERT will ALWAYS create a new row (or error out). Depending on your table structure you may be able to do something like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival) 
VALUES (
 '".$Team."',
 '".$cp."00' 
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CP2_Arrival='".$cp."00'";
```

However, that would require the Team column to be either a unique index or primary key. If that is not the case, you would need to do some sort of check on the table to decide if you want to insert or update and then either run the insert statement you have or run an update statement like so:

```
$sql="UPDATE checkpoints SET CP2_Arrivale='".$cp."00' WHERE Team='".$Team."';
```

If you want to add the Team column as a primary key try:

```
ALTER TABLE checkpoints ADD PRIMARY KEY(Team);
```

Comment: was just about to write the same, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the  correct solution for OP

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as i understand, you can define `Team` columns as Primary key (or Unique key).
Then you can use following statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival)
VALUES (
 '".$Team."',
 '".$cp."00' 
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CP2_Arrival = '".$cp."00';
```

In this case you will insert new row if there is no such `Team` or update `CP2_Arrival` in other case.
You can read more about this here: [insert-on-duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Also you can use `REPLACE` ([REPLACE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)) instead of `INSERT` (this also required Primary/Unique key):

```
$sql="REPLACE INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival)
VALUES (
 '".$Team."',
 '".$cp."00' 
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I've got it working now. Firstly I changed the coding to what most people suggested (see below) Also Truncated the tabke then make Team a primary key. tested this and it is now working

```
$sql="INSERT INTO checkpoints (Team, CP2_Arrival) 
VALUES (
 '".$Team."',
'".$cp."00' 
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CP2_Arrival='".$cp."00'";
```